# User Permissions/Submit Forms in Django

Tags: python, html, django, user-controls, user-input

Writing a simple Q&A site that allows users to ask and answer each other's questions.

I want to segment users to give them permissions, and I'm assuming the best way is to create groups. (Let me know if I'm wrong.) Would like to create a group and have every user that signs up automatically join a group. Then that user has can submit data into a CharField and upload an image if they want.

```
#models.py
class name(models.Model):
    title      = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    image      = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images')
    pub_date   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    author     = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Now assuming a user is already registered and currently signed in,

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = pattners(
     url(r'^add/$', addQ)

#views.py
def addQ(request): #I know I'm probably missing something in the view)
    return render_to_response("add.html")

#add.html
<h1>Add</h1>
<form action = "" method = "post">{% csrf_token %}
    <label for = "AddQ"> Add: </label>
    <input type = "text" name = "add" value = "" id = "add">
    <label for = "image1"> Image: </label>
    <input type = "image" name = "image1" value = "" id = "image1">

    <input type = "submit" value = "Add" />
```

So what do I need to do to enable users to add a question to the model?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Need to know what to add to allow users to add posts, and how to automatically add users to a group with predefined permissions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get user input, use forms.

See the [django doc on forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) for more info.

To update the DB, use the django ORM. And here are the [appropriate docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/instances/).